# Couldn't find matching GLX visual

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I'm struggling to initialise an OpenGL display using `pygame` and `pyopengl`.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL)
```

gives the error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
```

If I don't specify `pygame.OPENGL` I get a properly initialised display and a pygame window.

- I'm using python 3 (`Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`)
- I'm on Manjaro Linux, running `i3` windows manager
- I'm on a Dell XPS laptop, which has both Intel and Nvidia graphics adapters and I'm using `optirun` to use the Nvidia hardware, but I get the same effect regardless of which graphics adapter I use
- `glxgears` and `optirun glxgears` both work fine, so I believe that OpenGL is available on the machine and working fine
- `optirun glxinfo` https://pastebin.com/v6VjZgBZ

In an attempt to find a suitable set of display parameters, I ran:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.Info())
print(pygame.display.list_modes(32, pygame.FULLSCREEN))
print(pygame.display.mode_ok((1920, 1080)))
print(pygame.display.mode_ok((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL))
```

Which gave the following output:

```
VideoInfo(hw = 0, wm = 1,video_mem = 0
         blit_hw = 0, blit_hw_CC = 0, blit_hw_A = 0,
         blit_sw = 0, blit_sw_CC = 0, blit_sw_A = 0,
         bitsize  = 32, bytesize = 4,
         masks =  (16711680, 65280, 255, 0),
         shifts = (16, 8, 0, 0),
         losses =  (0, 0, 0, 8),
         current_w = 3200, current_h = 1800

[(3200, 1800), (2880, 1620), (2560, 1600), (2560, 1440), (2048, 1536), (2048, 1152), (1920, 1440), (1920, 1200), (1920, 1080), (1856, 1392), (1792, 1344), (1680, 1050), (1600, 1200), (1600, 900), (1400, 1050), (1400, 900), (1368, 768), (1280, 1024), (1280, 960), (1280, 800), (1280, 720), (1024, 768), (1024, 576), (960, 540), (864, 486), (800, 600), (720, 405), (640, 480), (640, 360)]
32
32
```

Below is an extract of `optirun glxinfo`, i.e. `glxinfo` for the Nvidia adapter, showing several GLX Visuals (full output https://pastebin.com/v6VjZgBZ):

```
70 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ce 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0cf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0da 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0db 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0dc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 None
0x0dd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0de 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0df 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ea 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0eb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ec 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ed 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ee 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ef 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0f8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 None
0x0fa 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0fc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fe 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ff 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x100 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x101 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x102 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x103 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x104 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x105 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x106 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x107 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x108 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x109 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10a 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10b 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10c 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10f 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x110 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

Please help me to diagnose the problem and get an OpenGL enabled pygame window going.

**Update 20190131**
I tried in `ipython` (python 3.6.2) setting 24-bit colour mode as suggested by @hidefromkgb, but I got the same issue (I had tried this before):

```
In [1]: import pygame

In [2]: pygame.init()
Out[2]: (6, 0)

In [3]: pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL, 24)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b9c85baaf5fe> in <module>()
----> 1 pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL, 24)

error: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
```

I am able to get OpenGL working from c++ using GLUT without problems.

**Update #2 20190131**

I have two minimal programs now (`python`, `c++`) with accompanying strace output (see https://paste.ee/p/ah1nq).

This `python` program fails with the *GLX Visuals* error:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL)
```

This `c++` programs succeeds in creating a window:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void) {
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("window initialisation test");
    return 0;
}
```

The `c++` program was compiled with `g++ test.cpp -lGL -lglut -o test`.

I had a look at the `strace` output, but couldn't make heads nor tails of it.

**Update #3 20190131**

I ran `ltrace` on the two above programs and got

`python`

```
$ ltrace python test.py
__libc_start_main(0x400ab0, 2, 0x7ffe171cfb58, 0x400cc0 <unfinished ...>
_PyMem_SetupAllocators(0x400da8, 0x7ffe171cfb58, 0x7ffe171cfb70, 0x7f82b2fd4578) = 0
PyMem_RawMalloc(24, 0x400daf, 0x7ffe171cfb70, 6)                                = 0xf8d260
PyMem_RawMalloc(24, 0xf8d270, 0xf8d260, 0xf8d260)                               = 0xf8d280
setlocale(LC_ALL, nil)                                                          = "C"
_PyMem_RawStrdup(0x7f82b2f9c007, 0, 0, 0xf8d280)                                = 0xf8d2a0
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")                                                           = "LC_CTYPE=en_AU.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=e"...
Py_DecodeLocale(0x7ffe171d1310, 0, 0, 0)                                        = 0xf90710
Py_DecodeLocale(0x7ffe171d1317, 0, 0xf90728, 0)                                 = 0xf90740
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")                                                          = "C"
PyMem_RawFree(0xf8d2a0, 16, 0, 0)                                               = 0
Py_Main(2, 0xf8d260, 0, 0xf8e260Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL)
pygame.error: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
)                                               = 1
_PyMem_SetupAllocators(0x400da8, 0x7f82b2fd6710, 0, 2880)                       = 0
PyMem_RawFree(0xf90710, 0x400daf, 0, 6)                                         = 0
PyMem_RawFree(0xf90740, 0xf90760, 0, 0xf90760)                                  = 0
PyMem_RawFree(0xf8d260, 0xf90700, 0, 0xf90700)                                  = 0
PyMem_RawFree(0xf8d280, 0xf8f310, 0, 0xf8f310)                                  = 0
+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

`c++`

```
$ ltrace ./test
glutInit(0x7ffd507caccc, 0x7ffd507cadb8, 0x7ffd507cadb8, 128)                   = 0
glutInitDisplayMode(18, 1, 0x7fb32b5c44e0, 32)                                  = 0x7fb32b7d70e0
glutCreateWindow(0x562359efe004, 1, 0x7fb32b5c44e0, 32)                         = 1
--- SIGWINCH (Window changed) ---
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

**Update #4 20190213**

Thanks for the input, @hidefromkgb.

I tried using `pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF` and also just passing `18`, but got the same result.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-59807ce30659> in <module>()
      3 
      4 pygame.init()
----> 5 pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

error: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
```

```py
print(pygame.OPENGL)
print(pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

2
1073741824
```

Comment: Please try to initialize a 24-bit color mode and see if GLX complains. From what I see, there are only a few 32-bit modes supported while all others are 24-bit.

Comment: @hidefromkgb I have already tried specifying 24-bit depth in the call to `set_mode` with the same result. See update to my original post.

Comment: Seems like you\`ll have to do it the hard way. You need to strip both your PyGame project and its GLUT counterpart of everything but GL initialization, and then run them using [`ltrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) to record all API calls they do. After that you\`ll need to search for GLX calls and compare their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry for the late answer, haven`t seen your edit before. In the future, please call people by nicknames in comments if you need to have their attention.

`ltrace` seems to have made the issue clearer. The first parameter to `glutInitDisplayMode` equals 18 which means `GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH`, for `GLUT_DOUBLE` = 2, `GLUT_DEPTH` = 16.

In its turn, `pygame.display.set_mode` call lacks both of these flags during GL initialization.

Try using `pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF` instead of just the `pygame.OPENGL`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem when using `pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF` or simply passing 18.
I did a search for `DOUBLEBUF` (within my anaconda3 installation) and found a number of hits. I tried `python anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/tests/image__save_gl_surface_test.py` and got exactly the same error when the unit tests ran, unsurprisingly.

Comment: @commander.trout Well… Now that definitely hints at an infrastructural issue. Standard tests that fail only mean one thing: something is broken inside the API stack between PyGame and GLX. `ltrace -f -S` should help with that.